# How add multiple rows plain html to existing table after a specific row dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table on a web page, I am trying to add multiple rows after first, second or third row dynamically.

```
<table class="sort-table">
   <tr>
      <th>State Owner</th>
      <th>Number of Orders</th>
      <th>Commission Total</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="so_details" data-name="Adam Howard" data-soid="2"><a class="so_link">Adam Howard</a></td>
      <td class="align-center">0</td>
      <td class="currency align-right">0.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="dashed-top">
      <td class="total" colspan="2">Total</td>
      <td class="currency align-right total">0.00</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I have created some new tr elements dynamically. following is the html

```
<tr>
   <td>ID1000</td>
   <td class="op_details" data-name="Adam Howard" data-opid="ID1000"><a class="op_link">Adam Howard</a></td>
   <td class="align-center">0</td>
   <td class="currency align-right">0.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>ID06</td>
   <td class="op_details" data-name="Cory McEwen" data-opid="ID06"><a class="op_link">Cory McEwen</a></td>
   <td class="align-center">0</td>
   <td class="currency align-right">0.00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="dashed-top">
   <td class="total" colspan="3">Total</td>
   <td class="currency align-right total">0.00</td>
</tr>
```

I want to insert the newly generated HTML tr elements after the first row or second or third etc.

I also want to adjust four td elements in newly created tr under the three td elements of a specific tr. as you can see in the code.
I have tried

```
let html = `<tr>
       <td>ID1000</td>
       <td class="op_details" data-name="Adam Howard" data-opid="ID1000"><a class="op_link">Adam Howard</a></td>
       <td class="align-center">0</td>
       <td class="currency align-right">0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>ID06</td>
       <td class="op_details" data-name="Cory McEwen" data-opid="ID06"><a class="op_link">Cory McEwen</a></td>
       <td class="align-center">0</td>
       <td class="currency align-right">0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dashed-top">
       <td class="total" colspan="3">Total</td>
       <td class="currency align-right total">0.00</td>
    </tr>`
(html).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
//$('.sort-table > tbody > tr').eq(1).after(html);
```

But nothing happened to dom and it remains unchanged. Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery insertAfter() or insertBefore() function can do your job.

```
insertAfter() // inserts after a selected element
insertBefore() // inserts before a selected element
```

syntax

> $("Your html goes here").insertAfter($('yourtable selector tr:eq(row
>   index after which you want to insert the html)'));

Here is an example.

```
<table class="sort-table">

<tr> <td> 1 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> 2 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> 3 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> 4 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> 5 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> 6 </td> </tr>

</table>
```

Now Javascript

```
var dynamicRow = `<tr>
                   <td>will insert after first row </td>
                 </tr>`;
$(dynamicRow).insertAfter($(".sort-table tr:eq(0)")); // 0th index is first-row

// The above 0th index using eq(0) can also be achieved using first-child pseudo selector

$(dynamicRow).insertAfter($(".sort-table tr:first-child"))


// if you want to insert after last row

dynamicRow = `<tr>
                   <td>will insert after last row </td>
                 </tr>`;

$(dynamicRow).insertAfter($(".sort-table tr:last-child"));
```

> Note: to give the row index in tr:eq(rowindex), always remember that
>   it starts from 0 not 1. so 
>             :eq(0) means first-row
>             :eq(1) means second-row
>             :eq(9) means (9+1) = 10th row